# How to describe a thin mist rising from the surface of a river?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I'm looking for a phrase to describe the kind of water vapour rising from the surface of a river in the morning. It doesn't have to be a single word but I wouldn't be surprised if there is one.

[image: what I'm trying to describe]

[image: what I'm trying to describe]

I'd call it *mist* or *fog* but, as far as I know, these could refer to something much thicker (particularly *fog*).

> As the sun climbed higher above the horizon, _________ rose from the surface of the river, enveloping the reeds.

*Fume* also comes to mind but it seems to have negative connotations.

Comment: Mist is said to rise, yes. Fog isn't said to rise and  there is a very famous poem about fog: Carl Sandburg: The fog comes/ on little cat feet. It sits looking/ over harbor and city/ on silent haunches/and then moves on. You can create your own image. There are many verbs you might use: drifted up, lifted up, come to mind.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz Lovely pictures. I have some similar taken just beyond my home, where the River Severn rolls past.

Comment: @1006a, thanks for linking to that question. I've had a look at those answers but I feel the ones provided here fit my use case better. _Wisps of mist_ seems like the perfect description of the shape and intensity I was thinking about. Jim's answer covers a range of water-related terms which was my other focus here.

Comment: How about "Vape" as in the trending vapour cigarettes?

Comment: You might want to make a quick edit to your question to clarify that you are more interested in a descriptive phrase, rather than a technical term, just in case anyone else looks and thinks they're the same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of references to '**wisps of mist**' in poetry and literature.

> wisps of mist float across the secluded horizon

[A Dairy Farmer's Daughter](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VAEtPzU6Ya8C&pg=PA212&dq=wisps+of+mist&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXnKu1otXYAhXBJMAKHRx_BrUQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=wisps%20of%20mist&f=false)

> curling wisps of mist were blowing through the top branches of the trees

[The Guide of Rhodes Castle](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CZTfAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA265&dq=wisps+of+mist&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXnKu1otXYAhXBJMAKHRx_BrUQ6AEIVTAI#v=onepage&q=wisps%20of%20mist&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

According to [*Mother Nature Network*](https://www.mnn.com/earth-matters/climate-weather/blogs/why-steam-fog-rises-ponds-morning)

> The phenomenon goes by many names, including steam fog, evaporation fog, frost smoke and sea smoke

These terms are probably not poetic enough for your use, and I tend to like some sort of "mist rising from the lake"  but beyond the technical names for this the question becomes "Primarily Opinion Based" and off-topic.

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking to a poetic name.